# How do I plot data from multiple CSVs each with different column numbers

Tags: python, scientific-computing

The file has no header but I would need to select say columns, 5,9, 13, 17 etc against column 2 (time). How can this be achieved in the case where the headers are present as well. Edit : Each file contains data for one day, the time format is GPS time which is the YR,Day of YR and Sec since midnight. How can i plot for say 1=30 January 2019?
Here is one code i tried

```py
    import numpy as np
    import glob,os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    files = glob.glob('*.s4')
    #print(files)
    for file in files:
        f=np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=3)
        #print(file[0:9].upper())
        for i in range (5,50,4):
            t=f[:,2]/3600.;s4=f[:,i]
            pos= np.where (t)[0]
            pos1=np.where(s4[pos]<0.15)[0];s4[pos1]='nan'
            plt.scatter(t,s4)
            #print(len(s4))
            plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 26, 2)) 
            #plt.title(str(i))
    plt.show()

The problem is that particular code only plots for one day at a time.
Here is a sample of the data.


19 001    45 11  1 0.07 214.9 37.5  8 0.08 314.5 34.2 10 0.14 102.6 14.3 11 0.07 241.2 49.6 14 0.07 152.0 50.0 18 0.05 212.7 68.0 22 0.08 226.1 33.7 27 0.06 346.0 22.0 31 0.04  63.5 47.7 32 0.06 144.3 30.4 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   105 11  1 0.05 214.9 37.9  8 0.07 314.9 33.8 10 0.24 102.2 14.1 11 0.07 241.7 49.9 14 0.06 151.9 49.6 18 0.06 213.0 68.4 22 0.12 225.7 34.0 27 0.06 346.2 21.7 31 0.04  64.1 47.9 32 0.06 144.2 30.0 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   165 11  1 0.06 214.9 38.4  8 0.11 315.3 33.5 10 0.12 101.8 13.9 11 0.06 242.3 50.1 14 0.06 151.8 49.1 18 0.05 213.4 68.9 22 0.07 225.2 34.2 27 0.11 346.5 21.3 31 0.04  64.8 48.2 32 0.10 144.0 29.6 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   225 11  1 0.06 214.9 38.8  8 0.06 315.8 33.2 10 0.10 101.4 13.7 11 0.06 242.8 50.4 14 0.05 151.7 48.6 18 0.04 213.7 69.4 22 0.06 224.8 34.4 27 0.08 346.8 20.9 31 0.05  65.5 48.4 32 0.09 143.9 29.2 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   285 11  1 0.06 215.0 39.2  8 0.11 316.2 32.9 10 0.14 100.9 13.6 11 0.05 243.4 50.6 14 0.06 151.6 48.2 18 0.06 214.1 69.8 22 0.08 224.4 34.7 27 0.07 347.0 20.5 31 0.06  66.1 48.6 32 0.09 143.7 28.8 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   345 11  1 0.06 215.0 39.7  8 0.08 316.6 32.5 10 0.10 100.5 13.4 11 0.04 244.0 50.9 14 0.06 151.5 47.7 18 0.04 214.6 70.3 22 0.07 223.9 34.9 27 0.08 347.3 20.2 31 0.07  66.8 48.9 32 0.08 143.6 28.4 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   405 11  1 0.06 215.1 40.1  8 0.07 317.0 32.2 10 0.13 100.1 13.2 11 0.05 244.6 51.1 14 0.08 151.4 47.3 18 0.05 215.0 70.8 22 0.07 223.5 35.1 27 0.12 347.5 19.8 31 0.08  67.5 49.1 32 0.12 143.4 28.0 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   465 11  1 0.06 215.1 40.5  8 0.12 317.4 31.9 10 0.10  99.7 13.0 11 0.08 245.2 51.4 14 0.05 151.3 46.8 18 0.06 215.5 71.2 22 0.06 223.0 35.4 27 0.12 347.8 19.4 31 0.03  68.2 49.3 32 0.18 143.3 27.7 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   525 11  1 0.09 215.2 40.9  8 0.12 317.9 31.5 10 0.11  99.3 12.8 11 0.04 245.8 51.6 14 0.15 151.2 46.4 18 0.06 216.0 71.7 22 0.06 222.6 35.6 27 0.08 348.0 19.1 31 0.05  68.9 49.5 32 0.08 143.1 27.3 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
19 001   585 11  1 0.07 215.2 41.4  8 0.09 318.3 31.2 10 0.12  98.9 12.6 11 0.04 246.5 51.8 14 0.06 151.1 45.9 18 0.05 216.5 72.2 22 0.06 222.1 35.8 27 0.08 348.3 18.7 31 0.07  69.6 49.7 32 0.11 143.0 26.9 138 0.09 282.0 17.8
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It'd also help if you reduce the sample data in your example and provide what code you've tried and why it isn't producing the output you expect.

Comment: I tried using pandas to concatenate the files into a dataframe do i can plot for more than one day since each file contains data for one day. The issue is the combined CSV has lots of empty spaces filled with commas and columns mixed up.                        
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("F:\\DATA\\SCINTILLATION DATA\\LBOA\\2018")
extension = 's4'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extensio
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ], sort=True)
combined_csv.to_csv( "LBOA2018.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a space character is the column separator, you can load them into a list of lists:

```py
data = []
with open(datafile,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
       # splits into list based on white space separator
       data.append(line.split)
```

Taking part of your example: to compare the values in column 2 with column 5 you could do:

```py
for line in data:
    if line[1] == line[4]:
       print("it's a match!")
```

If you have a header you want to ignore, just skip the first line when you open the file:

```py
with open(datafile,'r') as file:
    # do nothing with this line
    header = f.readline()
   ...
```

Comment: How can i use this for multiple files i.e, each file = 1 day of data?

Answer (score 0):

The solution by John definitely worked. I used Pandas to read in the files into a list of lists then concatenated them into one big dataframe that way I can use the datetime index to plot any interval I want.

```
data = []
with open(datafile,'r') as file:
for line in file:
   # splits into list based on white space separator
   data.append(line.split)
Bigdata = pd.DataFrame(data)
```